# How to bind `click` on links in dynamic loading content?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have some weird problem. Let's assume we have an HTML page with the following code:

```
<div class="description">
        <a href='#' class='oldkeenload btn btn-apply' data-subject='1' data-subject2='3'><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Загрузить материал</a>
</div>
```

When user clicks the href button with the class oldkeenload I do the following js code:

```
$(".oldkeenload").click(function () {
    // console.log("Clicked");
    var topic=$(this).data('subject');
    var kcode=$(this).data('subject2');

    var datastring = '/app/server.php?oldkeen=' + kcode + '&topicid=' + topic;

    // console.log(datastring);

    // var parentTag = $( this ).parent().get( 0 ).tagName;
    // console.log("Parent tag: " + parentTag);

    $(this).parent(".description").load(datastring);

    return false;
});
```

It just loads the response from the server to the "description" div. I do this to avoid loading all the materials, letting user load what he needs in one specific category. User sees intro to the material, presses the load button, the contents load.

However, when you load with this method the new links in the loaded content fails to load new contents. When I click the link nothing happens.

Any idea how to do it in JS without server side scripting?

Comment: A page's source code is not updated as a result of client-side DOM manipulation. Use your browser's dev tools to inspect the DOM.

Comment: I know, that is the problem. Is there a way to update the DOM. I have the href element inside the loaded content I want to manipulate.

Comment: The DOM *is* updated. Otherwise you wouldn't see the change on the page itself.

Comment: Ok probably I'm incorrect. I want to pass the href click inside the loaded content to another function in js file. But it does not recognize the click and the contents to pass

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're experiencing. Did your page content updated when clicking the link? Have you try DOM Inspector in your browser? (as other people mentioned, it is impossible to change the server HTML with client-side javascript, only the DOM is changed)

Comment: As you have explained above that I cannot change the source code. So i cannot use contrcutions like  $(".toolmoda").click(function(){ - for the newly loaded HTML, I have decided to do the content management in this case in the server side.

Comment: To make it clear I have an <a href="#" class="toolmoda"> in the loaded content. But when I try to address it with jquery I get no result, as there is no <a href="#" class="toolmoda"> in the source code, only in my eyes :)

Comment: As far as it is in the DOM, you can still find that with Javascript later on. If you problem is that you cannot click the link `<a href='#' class='oldkeenload>` on the loaded content, its because your `click` binding runs before that link exists.

Comment: If you re-run the binding javascript after the new content is loaded, you can still bind it again and have it load the "next-next page" on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function accept an extra callback. It will be run after the load is done. You can bind the `click` function again after the DOM is updated by `.load`.

```js
var loadData = function () {
    // console.log("Clicked");
    var topic=$(this).data('subject');
    var kcode=$(this).data('subject2');

    var datastring = '/app/server.php?oldkeen=' + kcode + '&topicid=' + topic;

    // console.log(datastring);

    // var parentTag = $( this ).parent().get( 0 ).tagName;
    // console.log("Parent tag: " + parentTag);
    var $container = $(this).parent(".description");
    $container.load(datastring, function () {
        $(".oldkeenload", $container).click(loadData);
    });

    return false;
}
$(".oldkeenload").click(loadData);
```